# Simple JSON unexpected token { at position > 1

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I'm trying to use JSON simple as part of a Java application to pull specific data from a .json file. Whenever I run the program, I get an unexpected token error message when it tries to parse.

A simplified version of the JSON file is as follows:

```
{"id":123,"text":"sample1","user":{"id":111,"name":"username"},"lang":"en"}
{"id":345,"text":"sample2","user":{"id":555,"name":"user2"},"lang":"en"}
```

My code is as follows:

```
public static void readJSON() {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    try {

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileLocation);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("");

        Iterator<?> i = jsonArray.iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) i.next();
            int tweetID = (int) obj.get("id");
            String lang = (String) obj.get("lang");         
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In this example, the line of code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
```

throws an error due to an unexpected token at the first left brace ({) of the second JSON object (i.e, at the brace before "id":345).

How could I go about resolving this issue? 
And, as a follow up, how would one also pull the information for the username in this example?

Thanks for taking the time to read through this, and for any assistance provided!

Comment: Essentially this is `{}{}` which is invalid in JSON. The JSON either needs to be an array in the file itself `[{}, {}]` or you need to parse it one line at a time

Comment: Your JSON is invalid I mean in a wrong format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That file is an invalid JSON file, it contains an entire object on each line.

What you'll need to do is read the file line by line, and then passing each line to the parser to create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

If you fix your code, you can solve unexpected token error.

```
public static void readJSON() {

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
try {

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileLocation);

    //You need to fix this part
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(reader);

    Iterator<?> i = jsonArray.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) i.next();
        int tweetID = (int) obj.get("id");
        String lang = (String) obj.get("lang");         
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse JSON object, and you actually have two JSON objects.
And in your code you are actually expect an array of JSON objects.
So, use the proper JSON array:

```
[
{"id":123,"text":"sample1","user":{"id":111,"name":"username"},"lang":"en"},
{"id":345,"text":"sample2","user":{"id":555,"name":"user2"},"lang":"en"}
]
```

In order to quickly check your JSON syntax, you can use some online [tool](http://jsonlint.com).

Answer (score -2):

Your JSON is indeed wrong. It actually contains 2 valid JSONs. If you want to create one valid JSON document you have to wrap your input with `{` and `}` or `[  ]` if this is an array or collection. Please note the comma that separates 2 different entities.

```
[
{"id":123,"text":"sample1","user":{"id":111,"name":"username"},"lang":"en"},
{"id":345,"text":"sample2","user":{"id":555,"name":"user2"},"lang":"en"}
]
```

Comment: Read my answer. This *may* be a valid json depending on the data model.